# Incompatible pointer types struct node to node

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, typedef, definition

I'm doing a lab for my course and I'm having an issue with some warnings. 
We are given a struct that we cannot change:

```
typedef struct Element{
    int value;
    double key1;
    double key2;
    struct NODE* next;
    struct NODE* sort1;
    struct NODE* sort2;
}Node;
```

And this is the main code:

```
struct Element * randomizer(int A){
     /*Function to have "real" random*/

    srand((unsigned int) time(0));

     Node *head;
     Node *ptr;
    int i = 0;

    head = NULL;
    ptr = NULL;



    /*Vlaues beiong intialized*/
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= A; i++){
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        ptr->value = rand()%11;
        while (ptr->value == 0 || ptr->value == 10 ){
            ptr->value = rand()%11;
        }
    ptr->key1 =  (rand()%41)+10;

        while (ptr->value == 10.0 || ptr->value == 50.0 ){
              ptr->key1 =  (rand()%41)+10;
        }
    ptr->key2 = (rand()%41)+50;

        while (ptr->value == 50.0 || ptr->value == 90.0 ){
                     ptr->key2 =  (rand()%41)+50;
               }

    ptr->next = head;

    head = ptr;
    }

    ptr->sort1 = NULL;
    ptr->sort2 = NULL;

    return ptr;
}
```

At `ptr->next = head;` I get an error saying

> incompatible pointer types assigning type node to struct node

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `Node` is a typedef for `struct Element`. `next` is `struct NODE *`, but `head is `Node *`.

Comment: Use sane loops. This is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct Element{
    int value;
    double key1;
    double key2;
    struct NODE* next;
    struct NODE* sort1;
    struct NODE* sort2;
}Node;
```

You declared two different structures. The first one has the type `struct Element` with the type alias Node and within its definition you declared the type `struct NODE`.

Even if there was not a typo and the data members have the type `struct Node *` instead of `struct NODE *` nevertheless the types `struct Node` and `Node` are not the same types.

You should declare the structure like

```
typedef struct Element{
    int value;
    double key1;
    double key2;
    struct Element* next;
    struct Element* sort1;
    struct Element* sort2;
}Node;
```

Comment: Yup thank you, i messaged my prof and he corrected the mistake for the assignment

Answer (score 1):

`head` is declared as `Node *`, and because of the typedef this is equivalent to `struct Element*`.

The `next` member is declared as `struct NODE *`.

`struct NODE *` is not the same as `struct Element *`.

You probably should change the struct member to

```
struct Element *next;
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much, this has worked. So now I have to email my prof lol since I can't actually change that

Answer (score 0):

C is case-sensitive, so `Node` and `NODE` are two different, unrelated things.  You're trying to use `Node` in your code, but the declaration you say you can't change has `NODE`, so they are incompatible.  You probably need to change your code to also use `NODE`.

Comment: I just tried that, and it causes my entire code to crash. I'm using Node cause that's what I declared the struct to be.